# WinAppDriver not able to locate the Open button in open file dialog box

Tags: winappdriver

I have made a application which opens a open file dialog box when I click a button. I have created the open file dialog box using the Open File Dialog function. I want to automate this application using Windows Application Driver for that I have to click on the open button inside the open file dialog box. but the windows application driver is not able to find this open button.
I tried using automation id Class name run time id x path but it is not working
any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: i was trying to find and click on the open button by using:  session.findElementByName("Open").Click(); but its not able to find the button through so i tried to use xpath and classname and automation id of button to find it but nothing worked

Comment: Are you able to find any other elements on that dialog, or just that one specifically?

Comment: yes i am able to find other elements but not that open button

Comment: before you find, you must ensure that you are on that page or your session is active on that page.
once you focus on that page, you can interact with its window elements.